# How do i highlight a background text in a text file?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have a dictionary collection that stores the starting position and the charecter values of a text file.

For example: a sample text file (a.txt) may contain text like *"how are you? how do you do?"*

I have indexed the above text as follows

```
Dictionary<long,string> charLocation = new Dictionary<long,string>(); 

charLocation[0] = "how" 
charLocation[1] = "ow" 
charLocation[2] = "w" 
charLocation[4] = "are" 
charLocation[6] = "e" 
charLocation[5] = "re" 
charLocation[11] = "?" 
charLocation[9] = "ou?" 
charLocation[10] = "u?" 
charLocation[8] = "you?" 
charLocation[13] = "how" 
charLocation[14] = "ow" 
charLocation[15] = "w" 
charLocation[17] = "do" 
charLocation[18] = "o" 
charLocation[21] = "ou" 
charLocation[22] = "u" 
charLocation[20] = "you" 
charLocation[26] = "?" 
charLocation[24] = "do?" 
charLocation[25] = "o?"
```

Now, I want to highlight each occurrence of "how" or "do" in the text file.

For this I want to first do a lookup in the dictionary collection and find each occurrence of the string, then open the text file and highlight the text for each occurrence.

How can i do this?

Comment: Highlight how?  On a web page?  In a form?  In some esoteric XML format with the `<highlight>` keyword? :)

Comment: Why are you not simply searching the text instead of using your index?

Comment: I need to highlight the search word in the text file itself. for example: the font of the search word ("how") can be changed as follows **how** or the background color can be changed out to highlight the search word..Please help!!!<br> @Jens - i cannot search for the word directly in the text but i need to build an index and then search the index for the word

Comment: What does this have to do with LINQ?

Comment: .txt files have no way of highlighting words in them, therefore I assume you want to display the contents of the text file to the user, highlighting the entered word? If so, you need to tell us how you display them. Winforms or WPF RichTextBox? Html in a browser?

Comment: What prevents you from simply searching? Performance issues? If so, your index will not help you in its current form, I think. There are full text search algorithms out there, probably faster than anything that one can hack together quickly. Take a look there!

Comment: @Jens - Since .txt files cannot be highlighted in notepad I was wondering if I could use WordPad, notepad++ or Textpad to display the contents of the textfile along with the highlighted search results.  i am developing a winforms application using c# 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but this should works.

```
public string HighLight (int startPoint, string text, string word)
{
  if (startPoint > = 0)
  {
    int startIndex = text.indexOf (word, startPoint);
    if (startIndex >= 0)
    {
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder ();
      builder.Append (text.Substring ( 0, startIndex));
      builder.Append ("<strong>");
      builder.Append (text.Substring (startIndex + 1, word.Length));
      builder.Append ("</strong>");
      builder.Append (text.Substring (startIndex + word.Length + 1));
      return HighLight ((startIndex + "<strong>".Length + "</strong>".Length + word.Length, builder.ToString (), word);
    }
  }

  //Word not found.
  return text;
}
```

So you could do :

```
string myText = "how are you? how do you do?";
string hightLightedText = HighLight (0, myText, "how");
```

And if my code has no errors, that would returns "`<strong>`how`</strong>` are you? `<strong>`how`</strong>` do you do?";

Then you can repalce `<strong>` and `</strong>` with wathever you want to "highlight" your text.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie to c# programming.. i am unable to understand the implementation of the solution to my problem. Could you please help me?

Comment: I updated my answer. I suggest you try it in debug mode, with a break point at the first line of the function, to understand how it works.